# Set mask dynamically using jquery and struts tag html:text

Tags: jquery, struts-1

I need to set a mask dynamically for a input. 
I am using this code:

```
function applyMask(element,mask){
    var $element = $('#'+element.id);
    $element.mask(mask);    
}
```

I am using struts tag `<html:text>` for the input and the mask is a string that comes from a property of an entity:

```
<html:text styleId="describerGroup" ...  onfocus="javascript:applyMask(this,${describer.formatedMask});" ... />
```

It seems the mask is being applied fine, but after that I can't type on the input. Maybe it some incompatibility from jquery with other javascript libs int the project. I am using this import to jquery's.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

Comment: '<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>'

the lib from mask

Comment: `$('#'+element.id)` could be replaced with `$(element)`